# XSLT remove source's stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I have my XSLT working, *except* I can't get it to remove (to not copy, to delete) the source file's `<?xsl-stylesheet...` element/directive.  Here's what I have for my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet"/>

   <xsl:template match="TestCase">
    ... remainder of file
```

I've tried it with and without a `"?"`, with and without the `"xsl:"` portion in the match attribute, no luck.  (So, I've tried the "match" being `"xsl:stylesheet"`, `"?xsl:stylesheet"`, `"stylesheet"`.)  The xml source starts off like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../testUtil testLogToHtmlDisplay.xsl" ?>
    <TestSuite Name="APIC2EChartAddRoute">
```

TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything starting `<?` (other then the `<?xml version=...?>` declaration) is a *processing instruction*, which you can match with a pattern of `processing-instruction('name')` (for a specific `<?name ...?>`) or just `processing-instruction()` (for any PI, regardless of name, the same way you would use `*` for any element node):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')"/>

   <xsl:template match="TestCase">
    ... remainder of file
```